# Unable to select data from combo box using CodedUI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am using CodedUI technology to do the automation.I have a combo box control and a grid inside as an item. I can find the combo box and managed to open the grid as shown in Fig (01) [Control with properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAfZF.png). Now,for further testing I need to click on row item inside the grid.

Issue : I couldn't find the grid and failed to navigate using the search properties. As you see in Fig (01) , the parent level is in desktop client and not bound to our application. Even though the grid belongs to the combo box visually, still it is not listed either parent or the application window.

Solution required: I need to select/click on row item in the grid using hand coded coded ui.

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkXRo.png)

Note : Playback control also failed to do the desire output.Clicking on the row based on mouse co-ordinates is not much appreciated.

Looking for the solution and thanks much in advance.

Comment: show some of your code that you tried

Comment: Added code snippet as png to the same thread. Please get back if you have any queries.

Comment: To be clear, you have the grid *inside* the combobox as a child??  That seems ... weird.  You select the grid as the selected item or interact with it after it is open.  Since this is a custom control, there may not be a great way to do this.  If they have not implemented the accessibility hooks, you won't be able to use most of the techniques you could otherwise.  I would find the combobox and set focus to it, then try sending keyboard down arrow to see if that can move into the combobox or maybe enter then arrow keys.  also, you can use the offset of a mouse click to click near the combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying the grid/Table with combobox as a parent instead of your main application.Something like this

if cboName is your combobox then

HtmlTable tbldata = new HtmlTable(cboName);

Provide any of the columnheaders or one of the Search Property to identify it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Hope you must have tried highlighting the grid and checked the parent.
Just try to do record and play u r case and generate code .And see code is getting generated ,how it is maintaing child parent relationship.Than u will get some idea and parameterized the thing in your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be able to clarify your answer please if you can help this user out!